# How to delete files older than x days with FORFILES?

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-server-2008-r2

OS: Windows Server 2008 R2

I've got a small batch file which should delete all backups older than x days in a specific folder.

Command:

```
forfiles /P "C:\LehrerOffice_Backup\BatchBackup\" /S /M *.* /D -31 /C "cmd /c del @PATH"
```

Error:

```
Invalid argument/option - '@PATH'. Type "forfile /h" for usage
```

Does anybody know what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the ending backslash in the /P argument

Comment: @SaintCore, sorry, for me, without the ending backslash that was escaping the quote making the `forfiles` parameter handling fail, it works without problems.

Comment: Didn't thought that it would be that simple, thank you anyway.

Comment: Yes it is working now. I was editing the wrong command(actually I was not editing the command above, I've changed another one which I tried out for testing purpose.)